# What is the standard way to ask when a store opens?

Tags: choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical, oral

Would it be « *Quand est-ce que vous ouvrirez ?* » ?

Likewise, how do you ask when they close? « *Quand est-ce que vous fermerez* ? » ?

Comment: On utilise le présent dans ce cas. C'est le présent qu'on appelle parfois « habituel ». C'est vrai tous les jours. On n'a pas déjà posé la question sur FL ?

Comment: @Laure il me semble aussi, mais je n'arrive pas à retrouver le sujet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce que tu veux savoir par ta question c'est l'heure d'ouverture habituelle du magasin, on utilisera donc le présent.

> À quelle heure ouvrez-vous ? À quelle heure fermez-vous ?

De même je dirais :

> Je me lève à six heures tous les jours.

On peut imaginer des cas où on emploierait le futur, ce serait pour décrire une situation particulière et non habituelle.
Sous les indications des horaires d'ouverture habituelle (par exemple 8h30 - 20h00), on pourrait voir le panneau suivant sur la porte d'un magasin en décembre :

> Le magasin ouvrira à 14h le 1<sup>er</sup> janvier.

Tu arrives devant un magasin encore fermé alors que d'habitude il ouvre à 8h30. En repartant tu croises le gérant en train de prendre un café au bistrot du coin, tu peux lui demander :

> À quelle heure allez-vous ouvrir /ouvrirez-vous aujourd'hui ?

Si l'emploi du futur dans ce cas est possible, l'emploi du présent l'est aussi.

> À quelle heure ouvrez-vous aujourd'hui ?

serait certainement le plus courant. Il ne s'agit plus dans ce cas d'un présent d'habitude mais d'un présent exprimant une action future soulignée pas une expression de temps.

Par ailleurs on emploierait « à quelle heure » et pas « quand » ici. On emploierait « quand » plutôt pour connaître la date que l'horaire. 
Exemple : on en est en train de finir les aménagements d'un nouveau magasin, tu veux savoir quand il va ouvrir (sous entendu, quel jour), tu demanderas :

> Quand est-ce que vous ouvrirez ?
>    Quand allez-vous ouvrir ?
>   Quand ouvrez-vous ?

Et la réponse serait quelque chose comme :

> La semaine prochaine. / Dans un mois...

Comment: Le futur me titille un peu dans "Quand est-ce que vous ouvrirez ?", j'aurais tendance à utiliser le présent. Est-ce que les deux sont valables ?

Comment: @Random Tu veux dire dans le dernier exemple ? Personnellement je n'emploierais pas le futur simple de toutes façons (mais le futur avec aller) mais je crois que c'est correct, non ? Bien sûr on peut employer aussi le présent dans cette phrase, le contexte est clair.

Comment: Je pensais à "Quand est-ce que vous **ouvrez**", mais je pense qu'elles sont toutes correctes oui...